# td not shrinking to fit contents, even though cell below it has height:100%

Tags: html, css

I am using a `<table>` to lay out some stuff.

```css
table {
  /**   width: 4.0cm;
        height: 6.472cm; **/
  width: 3cm;
  height: 4.85cm;
  border: 1mm solid black;
  font-style: serif;
  font-size: 8.5pt;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.image {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1cm;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td.description {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 6.5pt;
  padding: 0.5ex;
  border-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 0.85;
}
```

```html
<table class="#Class">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="usage">#Usage</td>
      <td class="headerspace" style="width:100%"></td>
      <td class="ap">#AP&nbsp;AP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="title">#Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="subtitle #CSSClass">#Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:3cm">
      <td colspan="3" class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bhiXsy4.jpeg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="description">#Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="footnotes">#Footnotes</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Full fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fcxjzbtn/).

What I ultimately want is for the `<img>` to fill the fill width and height of the `<td>` if possible, limit the height to a specific maximum; and for either dimension to shrink if required to preserve the aspect ratio. Furthermore, the `<td class="image">` should shrink vertically if the `<td class="description">` pushes it upwards.

It renders like this

[image]

The `<td class="image">` exceeds its `height:1.5cm`. I was expecting it to shrink to contain the `<img>` since the `<td class="description">` below it has `height:100%`.

Why is this not happening?

Comment: #Class is likely not a valid class name. It is for sure not a good class name since the `#` is an ID selector

Comment: Don't use tables for layout; use tables for tabular data. Try CSS instead

Comment: It's a template where #FOO gets substituted

Answer (score 0):

If you add a border to each td element on the page, you can see the image is fitting appropriately to the container it is sitting within.

To make the image display the way I'm assuming you are wanting, you'll need to remove the height on the parent element the image is sitting within.

There was actually a few more extra added stylings which were getting in the way of the desired layout - see the below snippet to see what you need to add and what you don't need:

```css
table {
  /**   width: 4.0cm;
        height: 6.472cm; **/
  width: 3cm;
  height: 4.85cm;
  border: 1mm solid black;
  font-style: serif;
  font-size: 8.5pt;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {
  width: 3cm;
  height: auto;
}

td.description {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 6.5pt;
  padding: 0.5ex;
  border-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 0.85;
}
```

```html
<table class="Class">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="usage">#Usage</td>
      <td class="headerspace" style="width:100%"></td>
      <td class="ap">#AP&nbsp;AP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="title">#Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="subtitle #CSSClass">#Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bhiXsy4.jpeg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="description">#Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="footnotes">#Footnotes</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

If I'm missing something please let me know, but this at least fixes the issue you had with your image not fitting the way you wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your solution doesn't render as desired -- the img should shrink vertically to the max height, and the #Description should expand, like [this](https://i.imgur.com/PFiczL6.png)